# How do I create a data validation list WITHOUT using cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, data-validation

I have a simple data validation dropdown that I'm trying to do, but I DO NOT WANT to use cells to populate my list.

Something similar to what's below, but this obviously isn't working.

[image]

What formula do I need to input to create a list of strings in a cell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you mean something else, no need to wrap in quotes, or use the "=" sign
[image]

Comment: Comma-separated values no longer work in newer versions of Excel, apparently. I figured you're supposed to use a semicolon now, like this: `TRUE;FALSE`

Answer (score 8):

You can put them in as a comma separated list:

```
true,false
yes,no
2,4,6,8
with space,without
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

So for anyone who might have run into this problem, I found the solution (or rather the cause).

I had previously tinkered with the locale parameters of my system and altered the list separator character to semicolon in Control Panel > Clock & Region > Region > Additional Settings. When I used that instead of comma, the dropdown worked. The question is now whether this will continue to work on a system with the standard separator.